# Linq to SQL - Find element with lowest field value - Performance

Tags: performance, linq, select

Today I am facing a problem of finding the most efficient query to database using Linq To Sql.

I want to get the element from db.ElementsCollection that has lowest element.SomeNumber value.

I simply managed to do it by following query:

```
var query = db.ElementsCollection
   .First(o => o.SomeNumber == (db.ElementsCollection.Max(or => or.SomeNumber)));
```

Is there any more efficient query to accomplish this task?

Comment: Add an index to the `SomeNumber` field on the database?  Otherwise it's going to be at least one table scan.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it what you want:

```
var maxNumber=db.ElementsCollection.OrderByDescending(o=>o.SomeNumber).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OrderByDescending` on the property `SomeNumber` and then get the first item:

```
var query = db.ElementsCollection
              .OrderByDescending(o => o.SomeNumber)
              .First();
```

Or you can use [morelinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/):

```
var query = db.ElementsCollection
              .MaxBy(o => o.SomeNumber);
```

Comment: But is it more efficient than the example I have written? About morelinq: seems nice but I'd prefer to use built in Linq

Comment: @user2014182: Not much efficient than, but at least it's more readable, like other's comment, you should index your column to make it more efficient.

Comment: And how can I accomplish that? Thanks

Comment: @user2014182: ;), how to accomplish? Ask another question

Comment: Um, I mean how to do the column indexing, sorry:P

Comment: @user2014182: I understand what you meant, that's why I suggest you can ask another question on here

Comment: @user2014182: well, you can post another question on Stackoverflow, instead getting answer via comment

Comment: The thing is I find it useless, as I am not able to modify the database (is not the point of what I am doing) and I believe there's also no possibility for linq to put indexes on columns in database..

Answer (score 1):

How about that:

```
var query = db.ElementsCollection.OrderByDescending(o => o.SomeNumber).First();
```

Or

```
var query = (from o in db.ElementsCollection
            order by o.SomeNumber descending
            select o).First();
```

It should be translated into `TOP(1)` within SQL Query.

Comment: From the research I've been doing in the internet for past two hours, it says that sorting the whole table to get the min/max element is way too slow. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user2014182 There will be no difference if you have an index on `SomeNumber` column.